# How does bootstrap know what the screen size is?

Tags: bootstrap-4, screen

I'm learning about bootstrap now and I'm just curious how it can tell what the size of the screen is. For example, on a device with a larger screen, you can change the size of the window. So if you change the size of the screen, does it act the same way as if were displayed on a smaller device?

Comment: They are using predefined media queries or breakpoints which change based on the width of the screen: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#all-breakpoints

Comment: Your Question: "So if you change the size of the screen, does it act the same way as if were displayed on a smaller device?"... Answer: yes, resize the window and check the behavior

Answer (score 0):

cant does bootstrap know what the screen size is. but jquery can get the screen size.

```
// Returns width of browser viewport
$( window ).width();

// Returns width of HTML document
$( document ).width();
```